# Tapestry: How to set HTML checkbox from java page

Tags: java, html, checkbox, tapestry, checked

I am using plain HTML checkbox(not Tapestry type). I need to set the checkbox to checked in my java page. How do I do that?

Here is my tml code fragment

```
<input type="checkbox" name="leaf" id="leaf" value="leaf"/>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Wait, do you want the checkbox to already be checked when the page loads?

Comment: For some of the checkbox, Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the checked property. I'd probably use the `<t:any>` component.

TML

```
<t:any element="input" type="literal:checkbox" name="literal:leaf" id="prop:clientId" value="prop:currentObject.value" checked="prop:checked" />
```

JAVA

```
@Property
private SomeType currentObject;

public String getClientId() {
    return "mycheckbox_" + currentObject.getId();
}

// if this returns null, tapestry won't render the attribute
public String getChecked() {
    return currentObject.isSelected() ? "checked" : null;
}
```